# In Powershell, how do I build a file by appending a string with another files' contents?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Powershell script that does the following:

1. Pulls down git ignore patterns from https://gitignore.io
2. Reads custom git ignore patterns from a text file on the filesystem
3. Appends both to a `.gitignore` file on disk, overwriting previous contents.

The end result should be a file with gitignore.io patterns PLUS any custom defined patterns from another file.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```bsh
Function gig {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$list
  )
  $params = ($list | ForEach-Object { [uri]::EscapeDataString($_) }) -join ","
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.gitignore.io/api/$params" | select -ExpandProperty content
}

gig angular,csharp,images,vagrant | cat gitignore-patterns.txt | sc .gitignore
```

I realize this script is invalid, as the last line doesn't even work. But I typed it up this way to try to show, logically, what I want. I'm normally working in Linux Bash scripts, so what I'm trying models that a bit, although I am realizing it doesn't translate well to Powershell. I'm hoping there's a way to pipe commands together, to build a string, that eventually gets piped out to a file. Or something equally simple.

Note that my research so far into this has shown piecemeal solutions, but no solution pulling this all together. For example, I saw SO questions showing how to concat two strings, write a string to a file, append to a file, etc. But no single solution involving all of them together. I'm hoping to get that bigger picture solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap both statements in an array subexpression `@()`, and pipe to `Set-Content`:

```
@(
    gig angular,csharp,images,vagrant
    Get-Content gitignore-patterns.txt 
) |Set-Content .gitignore
```